# Remove element from mutable list - removeIf

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, mutablelist

```
    private var cardsList: MutableList<SomeObject>? = null
    val condition = Predicate<SomeObject> {
        it.id() == cardId
    }

    cardsList?.toMutableList()?.removeIf(condition)

    getNavigator()?.initRecycleView(cardsList)
```

I have one element in list; I have verified the id to be the same as cardId.

When I run the above code i expect that after `removeIf` is called, the `cardsList` will be empty, but it still has one element.

`removeIf()` returns `true` when called with `condition`.

I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually deleting anything from `cardsList`.
`cardsList?.toMutableList()` creates another mutable list object and deletes from that.
You should do:

```
cardsList?.removeIf(condition)
```

*Edit* from your comment.
I suspect that although you have declared `cardsList` to be `MutableList` somewhere along the way you did something like:

```
cardsList = listOf(...) as MutableList<SomeObject>
```

and so `cardsList` is not actually a mutable list.
If this is the case then before you remove the item do this:

```
cardsList = cardsList?.toMutableList()
```

and then:

```
cardsList?.removeIf(condition)
```

Comment: `private var cardsList: MutableList<SomeObject>? = null`

if is use removeIf() directly on cardsList, I got and exception: UnsupportedOperationException;

Comment: How do you ad items to cardsList?

Comment: you were right. i updated `cardsList` from the server response (who responded with a `List`) and instead of adding items, I used `=` operator; `  cardsList = serverResponse.data()`

Answer (score -2):

try cardsList?.removeIf {someObject->someObject.id == cardId}

Comment: if is use removeIf() directly on cardsList, I got and exception: UnsupportedOperationException